# which jQuery Class should i use in this scenario?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the images to move from right to left one-by-one when the mouse is over the arrow button, but I am unable to understand how and which jQuery class I can implement to execute the exact result.

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
<div id="logos">
    <ul>
        <li style="float:left; margin-left:0px; margin-right:40px; "><img src="images/logo&typography_porjects.png" width="300" height="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/logo-no-image.jpg" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/logo-no-image.jpg" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/logo-no-image.jpg" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/logo-no-image.jpg" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/logo-no-image.jpg" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/logo-no-image.jpg" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <li style="float:left; margin-left:0px;"><img src="images/logo-no-image.jpg" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/logo-no-image.jpg" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/logo-no-image.jpg" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/logo-no-image.jpg" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/logo-no-image.jpg" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/logo-no-image.jpg" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/logo-no-image.jpg" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/logo-no-image.jpg" height="130" width="130" /></li>              
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS code is:

```
#logos { width:1200px; float:right; }
#logos ul { list-style:none; float:right; overflow:hidden; }
#logos ul li { display:inline; margin:0 0 0 10px; }
.clear { height:30px; width:100%; clear:both; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create this effect is quite simple, you have two divs, one outter div hides the overflow of the inner div which moves left and "right" by altering the `margin-left` to a negative value.

### HTML

```
<div id="hide_overflow">
<div id="moving_panel">
   <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <!-- [... etc ... ] !-->
   </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using `<li>` in the above example but you can easily change these to `<img>`

### CSS

```
li {
    background: lightgray;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
}

#hide_overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#hide_overflow, #moving_panel {
    height: 70px;
}
```

### jQuery

```
$('#left').click(function() {
    var $panel = $('#moving_panel');
    if (!parseInt($panel.css('margin-left'))) return;
    $panel.animate({
        marginLeft: '+=200'
    });
});

$('#right').click(function() {
    $('#moving_panel').animate({
        marginLeft: '-=200'
    });
});
```

This is a very basic example to get you started. There are tons of these image slideshow-type plugins available for jQuery.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/9mYJk/

Comment: i am using jQuery in my page also, but these jQuery codes are not working with me ... not even a single move :(

Comment: Make sure your using `$(document).ready(function() { // code here });`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jQuery effects, like for example this one: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Or use toogle with some image transformations, like changeing image top and left coordinates.

Comment: but could you please little bit describe about this.

Answer (score 0):

And [here is my take at it](http://jsfiddle.net/majidf/GXtmu/embedded/result,js,html,css/). It has no animation (well, the motor is one line!)

The code? This:

```
$('#arrow').click(function() {
    $('li:first').after($('li#arrow_li').prev());
});
```

Markup (almost unchanged):

```
<div id="logos">
    <ul>
        <li style="float:left; margin-left:0px; margin-right:40px; "><img src="http://www.ssvworks.com/images/arctic_cat_logo2.png" width="300" height="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.nytha.com/design/logo.png" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.nytha.com/design/logo.png" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.nytha.com/design/logo.png" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.nytha.com/design/logo.png" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.nytha.com/design/logo.png" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.nytha.com/design/logo.png" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li style="float:left; margin-left:0px;"><img src="http://www.nytha.com/design/logo.png" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.nytha.com/design/logo.png" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.nytha.com/design/logo.png" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.nytha.com/design/logo.png" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.nytha.com/design/logo.png" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.nytha.com/design/logo.png" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.nytha.com/design/logo.png" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://homeflooringonline.com/product_image/Area/logo-rugs-auburn-universi836.jpg" height="130" width="130" /></li>
        <li id="arrow_li"><img src="http://china.keyence.com/products/sensors/fiberoptic/fsn/problem_arrow2.gif" height="130" width="60" id="arrow" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS (with a minor change):

```
#logos { width:900px; position: absolute; left: 54px; }
#logos ul { list-style:none; float:right; overflow:hidden; }
#logos ul li { display:inline; margin:0 0 0 10px; }
.clear { height:30px; width:100%; clear:both; }
```